# if statement with multiple and or statement in SAS

Tags: sas

```
if stdate <= LOS <= Enddate and Stdate <= DOS <= Enddate and paydt <= NoV2021 
and Soldate <=Dec2022 and Clst in ("P" "D") then comp=1; else compe=0
```

with the above code in SAS the clst is not picking values with D its only picking values with P. what must be the issue?

Comment: I think the correct format is `Clst in ("P","D")`

Comment: SAS does not care if you use commas or spaces to delimit the list of values for the IN operator, you can even mix them `x in (1,2 3 4,5)`

Comment: Are you sure their are any observations with CLST='D'? Note that 'd' and ' D' are not the same as 'D'.

Comment: What are the values of the variables `stdate`, `enddate`, `los`, `dos`, `paydt`, and `soldate` in the rows that have `CLST = 'D'`? According to the rules of `AND` logic one of the sub-expressions **must** resolve to false.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for all of the the observations that do have Clst="D" one or more of the other conditions are not true.

For `A and B` to be true both A and B need to be true.

Comment: Thanks everyone! looks like I wasn't adding proper date range filter which made me assume the clts was the issue.